# Bundled image in React Native not found on Android

Tags: android, bundle, react-native, assets

I'm building a React Native App for both ios and android. Assets (images, sounds, etc.) are all stored locally and preloaded during App's launch by a manager for later use.

Everything works fine on ios in debug & release modes and on android in debug mode but images won't display on android in release mode, even after bundling them.

First assets are preloaded from the Asset Manager in `src/assets/index.js`

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'

const assets = {
    images: {
        'icon.png': require('./images/icon.png')
    }
}

const preloadedAssets = {}

const getImage = (name, extension = 'png') => {
    return getAsset('images', `${name}.${extension}`)
}

const getAsset = (type, name) => {
    return preloadedAssets[type][name]
}

const preloadImages = () => {
    preloadedAssets.images = {}

    return Promise.all(
        Object.keys(assets.images).map(name => {
            const source = Image.resolveAssetSource(assets.images[name])

            return Image
                .prefetch(source.uri)
                .then(() => {
                    preloadedAssets.images[name] = {
                        source: assets.images[name],
                        ...source
                    }
                })
        })
    )
}

const preload = () => {
    return preloadImages()
}

export default {
    preload,
    getImage
}
```

Then images are rendered as follow

```
import AssetManager from '../assets'
const asset = AssetManager.getImage('icon.png')
<Image source={asset.source} style={{ width: ..., height: ... }} />
```

I bundled with the following command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

I also tried to copy all assets to `android/app/src/main/assets/` folder and replace `require('./images/icon.png')` with `{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/images/icon.png' }` but images are still not displayed.

Project structure

[image: project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a react-native project from scratch on version 0.59.4 (previously 0.57.1).

Now everything's working fine, apks can be generated without bundling with following commands :

```
cd android && ENVFILE=../.env.production ./gradlew assembleProdRelease && cd ..
cd android && ENVFILE=../.env.development ./gradlew assembleDevRelease && cd ..
```

I also removed `Image.prefetch` as it won't work on android release.